# why type of Object is a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, object

im having a hard time understanding why type of Object and even String and other data types is a function, is it a function constructor ?

```js
console.log(typeof Object);
// function
```

Comment: "*Is it a constructor?*" - yes. Try calling it!

Comment: see: [Object() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Object), [String() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/String)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this syntax instead....

```
console.log(typeof {}); // "object"
console.log(typeof new Object); // "object"
```

All object type constructor functions, when initiated with the *new* keyword will always have a type of “object”.

Comment: All constructor functions… except for function constructors.